# Matrix division element by element matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the following vectors:

```
a = [1 2];
b = [0.25 0.5];
```

I'd like to obtain a 2x2 matrix `c`:

```
c = [1/0.25+1/0.5  2/0.25+1/0.5  
     1/0.25+2/0.5  2/0.25+2/0.5];
```

I aim to expand this model with more values at a later date

thanks

Comment: I hate to ask this but.. What have you tried?

Comment: Try `bsxfun(@rdivide,a,b')`

Answer (score 4):

Linear algebra at its finest:

```
(1./b')*a
```

Comment: The simplest way is oft the finest. +1.

Comment: im realy sorry i slightly mis presented the question , its difficult to visualise

Comment: `1/2 + 1/4 = a(1)/c(1) + a(1)/c(2)`. Please, explain what you need because is still unclear.

Comment: sorry just for extra clarafication the values of a and b vary according to all possible combinations, and each are divided by the corresponding element in c a(i)/c(1) and b(i)/c(2). the values are then summed and stored as an element with an results matrix.

Comment: @mathew Please rewrite your original question. Examples on how one gets a particular solution is much appreciated

Comment: apologies for the uninformative question definatly wont happen again

Answer (score 0):

`repmat(a,size(b,2),1)./repmat(b',1,size(a,2))`

Comment: Hi guys any ideas as to the best approach to solve the problem

Comment: I made an attempt to use rdivide and store the values in matrix res1 then a ldivide stored in res2 them summed each elemt in a res3 matrix. I have no further ideas and would greatly appreciate any advice

Comment: could someone please delete this question as it was misrepresented and i have re written the original question